# Edit tags command not found next to tag list in questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

On Stack Overflow, there is an "edit tags" button or somesuch that will appear when you mouse-over the area to the right of the tag list on a question. It allows you to edit the tags of a question without bring up the whole edit box for the rest of it.

Even when you can freely edit questions and answers, I find this button useful for just editing tags. Do other people not see it, or is it just me? Is this intentional or a bug in the site?

Comment: I see the UI you're describing, both on main and meta. It doesn't seem to me like it should be behind a privilege gate that I have but you don't (retagging is granted at 500 reputation). Maybe it's a browser issue? I'm running Safari.

Comment: I'm using Firefox, the current version. I do have some unusual zoom settings, that sometimes broke certain SE sites. So it's entirely possible that it's local. I just don't know *what* is local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get access to inline edits until you get the moderator tools privilege at 10k rep.